# PHP __get magic method unexpected behaviour

Tags: php

I have following classes.

```
class Book {

    protected $name;
    protected $cost;
    protected $description;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->name = 'The X';
        $this->cost = 19.95;
        $this->description = 'Something about X';
    }

    public function __get($variable){
        return $this->$variable;
    }
}
```

---

```
class ReaderAbstract {

    protected $_book;

    public function __construct(){
        if(null == $this->_book){
            $this->_book = new Book();
        }
    }

    public function __get($variable){
        $method = 'get'.ucwords($variable);
        if(method_exists($this, $method)){
            return $this->$method();
        }
        return $this->getBook()->__get($variable);
    }

    public function getBook(){
        return $this->_book;
    }

}
```

---

```
class Reader extends ReaderAbstract {

    public function getCost(){
        return round($this->cost, 2);
        //return round($this->getBook()->cost, 2); Doing this works as expected
    }

}
```

Now if I do this.

```
$reader = new Reader();
echo $reader->name; //This should work
echo '<br />';
echo $reader->cost; //This should go into an infinite loop
echo '<br />';
echo $reader->description; //This should work
```

The code above works fine expect the statement `echo $reader->cost;` throws `"Undefined property: Reader::$cost"` error.

My questions here are:

1. Why I can't access the property `$cost`?
2. Shouldn't the call to $cost property trigger an infinite loop? I.e. Each time I call $reader->cost the call gets redirected to getCost() method and inside the getCost() method if I call $this->cost shouldn't it call the method getCost() creating an infinite loop?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Fine example of why you don't want to use `__get` for these things. Use regular Getters and Setters and you won't have this problem. And it will be easier to follow.

Comment: @Gordon: I agree. But I don't have a choice. Some other developer has all ready done this. And I am trying to understand the cause so I can resolve it.

Comment: Then undo it. It's not like it's much work and you can only benefit from it.

Comment: Seriously: don't ever use `__get` and `__set` if it's not absolutely necessary (which means that you can't do otherwise). And even then, try to refactor your code first. This is surely not the case to use such constructs.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I avoid using __get and __set but I am working on a Zend_Framework project which was developed by someone else. The developer had used his own Row classes instead of Zend_Db_Row_Abstract and rather then accessing the data of retrieved row using $this->getRow()->propertyName the developer came up with this solution so the data can be retrieved just using $this->propertyName..I can't change the above because that would mean modifying lots of views...

Comment: This came up on Meta and the "my eyes are bleeding" comment cries for justification. Indeed, it wasn't OP. Everyone's eyes are bleeding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `__get` method is not reentrant, so when you access `$reader->cost` it is called for the first time and will call `Reader::getCost()`, but then `$this->cost` forces PHP to do a recursive call to `__get` which will be denied.

I don't know if it's a bug or a feature. Read [this page from the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) and search for 'recursi' for further reading.